# Dropdown value changes on hover in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In Firefox if I click on a dropdown and hovering on the list, and while hovering if I take the value of the dropdown it shows the hovered value even without clicking it.

Suppose I have:

```
<select size="1" class="form-control input-sm input-element" name="fiveMod" id="fiveMod">   
<option value="[6FAM]">6-FAM (fluorescein)</option>
<option value="[HEX]">HEX</option>
<option selected="selected" value="[JOE]">JOE </option>
<option value="[TET]">TET </option>
```

Here the selected value is JOE. If I run the following code,

```
$('#fiveMod > option').hover(function(){
   console.log($('#fiveMod').val());
});
```

It is printing the value which I hover in the list. This creates problems in some situations where I am calling an ajax request and in success, if I hover through dropdown, it is taking the wrong value even without clicking it. (The HTML is generated through JSF)

Comment: Why do you need to bind `mouseenter/mouseleave` events to the `option` elements? Not clear what is your expected behaviour

Comment: It's not clear what behavior you need to reach. Do you need to get the value of the dropdown itself, on hover, or the value of the option you are hovering over? because you bound the even to the option itself, but getting the value of the dropdown... slightly illogical

Comment: I need to get the value of dropdown itself. I  think on hovering through options should not change the value of dropdown itself (It does in FF). The code with cosole.log is just to replicate the issue, not for real usage.

Comment: @tomin, find out my edited answer, Apparently <option> elements do not fire hover events in IE as well... so if you want to do it right, I'd encourage you to skip this idea at all, and to do it the other way around.

Answer (score 1):

You should get not the value of the dropdown itself, but the value of option you hover:

```
$('#fiveMod > option').hover(function(){
   console.log($(this).prop("value"));
});
```

Or if you need to get the value of the dropdown itself - then bind even to the dropdown itself, not to the options.

Apparently `<option>` elements do not fire hover events in IE as well, so I don't think this approach chosen is correct at all. If you need specific behavior for this, I'd recommend to skin the dropdown's behaviour with CSS+JS and emulate it with divs or links, through which you may do the correct hover behavior.

Comment: Good point but you should consider to bind only `mouseenter` event instead. BTW, this wouldn't work on chrome but it is really not clear what is OP's expected behaviour, so you get my vote...

Comment: Yes, the expected behavior is not clear. I asked the question in my comment to the topicstarter. See above.

Comment: Expected behavior: If I take $('#fiveMod').val(), while hovering/moving mouse through option values, I should not get the value which I hover ,  instead I want the selected value. It works as expected in Chrome.

Comment: @tomin, I think the behavior you want to reach hard to make cross-browser. I'd avoid binding hover events on options, as *it's not predictable in IE and Firefox* and depends on version. If you need to get this behavior - the normal practice is to emulate the dropdown with JS and CSS, then you may do the proper hover events over divs, links, etc.

Comment: @A.Wolff , @ Farside : Is there any way we can stop FF from changing the  value of the dropdown while hovering the options. ?

Comment: @tomin, FF never changed the value of <select> on **hover** event over <options>. How this question relates to my answer?